# Action buttons are not visible in Task related list in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-experience, tasks, related-list, button, relatedlistnew

I created a new object called Main Task and created a lookup on Task(Activity) to make a relationship between Task(Child) and Main Task(Parent).
I added task related list(Sub Tasks) into Main task page layout but I can't see the new task button and view, edit actions in Task related list in lightning view, but I can see all these actions in classic view.
I tried below steps, but couldn't fix the issue.

1. Ticked new task button from page layout-> related list ->wrench icon
2. Lightning app builder -> related list - enhanced list, show list view action bar - ticked

[image: Lightning View]
[image: Classic View]
Could someone please help me to fix this ?

Comment: Can you add related list single and select sub task as related list in your lightning app builder

Comment: Tried it. It didn't work. New button is visible for other related lists. I just can't see new button in Task related list in lightning. It's visible in classic.